# Show text in 2 colors in same column same cell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to display text in two colors based in same column and same cell in DataGridView in Windows Application Winform .NET. As Shown in below picture. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: You need to ownerdraw the DGV ie code the cellpainting event. There are many examples around here..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got the solution from [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cb3a4c96-e4f0-4474-aa71-18c5eedf2f65/how-to-set-different-color-for-text-in-indentical-datagridview-cell?forum=winforms)

Adding cellpainting event processing method perfectly solved this problem.

```
void datagridview_CellPainting(object sender,DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
  if(datagridview.Columns[e.ColumnsIndex].Name=="content")
  {
      string content="this is a test message,to illustrate this words fine";
      string []line=content.Split(',');
      StringFormat sf=new StringFormat();
      sf.Alignment=StringAlignment.Center;
      sf.LineAlignment=StringAlignment.Center; 

      e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All&~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);

      SizeF []size=new SizeF[line.Length];
      for(int i=0;i<line.Length;++i)
      {
          size[i]=e.Graphics.MeasureString(line[i],e.CellStyle.Font);
      }

      RectangleF rec=new RectangleF(e.CellBounds.Location,new Size(0,0));
      using(SolidBrush bblack=new SolidBrush(Color.Black),bred=new 
                                                    SolidBrush(Color.Red))
      {
           for(int i=0;i<line.Length;++i)
           {
               rec=new RectangleF(new 
                       PointF(rec.Location.X+rec.Width,rec.Location.Y),new 
                              SizeF(size[i].Width,e.CellBounds.Height));
               if(i%2==0)
               {                  
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(line[i], e.CellStyle.Font, bred, rec, sf);
               }
               else
               {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(line[i].e.CellStyle.Font, bblack, rec, sf);
               }
           }
      }
      e.Handled=true;
  }
}
```

Code above makes "this is a test message to illustrate this words fine" display within a cell in the column content, with  "this
 is a test message" in red color and "to illustrate this words fine" in black color.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @TaW there is answer if you click on the link, you will get full details

Comment: Link only answers are not welcome here. Links go dead all the time..

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom column with a rich textbox. Take a look at 
[this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31823/RichTextBox-Cell-in-a-DataGridView-2)

Comment: Possible but may well be overkill.